# Asking a question related to Programming

Tags: support, asking-questions

When asking a question that has to do with programming of android phones (rather than the phone OS itself) is it considered off topic? Like if I ask a question about how to develop an app on android using Java.

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic also